# How to call a method as soon as constructor is completed?

Tags: c#, constructor

How can I call a method every time when constructor is executed? 
In other words, 
Within a class, can I somehow call another method as soon as constructor is completed?

Comment: Call the method in the constructor at the end of the construction code?

Comment: Any reason you don't just want to put the call into the constructor itself? A piece of sample code would help.

Comment: @Jon: No reason at the moment, but will there be any problem if someone derives the class and calls the base constructor?

Comment: Then it will indeed be called before the subclass constructor is run. This seems like an odd requirement though. Perhaps if you give us more information we can suggest alternative designs.

Comment: Thank you. My previous comment was more of an academic question. I have been trying several things for learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just call the method as the last line of the constructor.

Alternatively if you don't own the class you can go for Aspect Oriented Programming ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_oriented_programming )

Comment: There are scenarios when the constructor might not be completed there, for instance if the constructor is invoked by the constructor in a derived class.

Answer (score 2):

No. Unless you call it **within** your constructor.

Alternatively you can have another method such as `Init()`, but the client needs to **remember** to call it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then this would be what you need?

```
public class SomeMethod
{
    public SomeMethod()
    {
       anotherMethod();
    }

    public void anotherMethod()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way syntactically for an inheritable class to restrict the calling of a constructor to code that is called from within another routine.  What is possible is to have a constructor throw an immediate exception unless it's given a valid special token, which can only be obtained via special routine which is called with a delegate, and which creates the token, passes it to the delegate, and then invalidates it after the delegate returns or throws.  That routine could then also take care of doing whatever needs to be done after the passed-in delegate either returns or throws.

Rather a nasty klunky hack, but unfortunately it's the only way I know of for a base class constructor ensure the cleanup of any unmanaged resources it owns if a derived-class constructor throws an exception.